# How to delete entire Db in Sqlite PhoneGap

Tags: sqlite, cordova, jquery-mobile, sql-delete

We developing PhoneGap app.We have 3 pages like page1 and page2 and Page3.We open db like this

```
var db;
db = window.openDatabase("SaleAppDb", "3.0", "saleAppDB", 5000000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

and then create and tables.We did ever page like this.We need When page1 loading it's enter db will be deleted and then again create and then table insert

Please guide me.Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

After scanning through the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#databases), I was not able to find how to exactly delete the database. You can though of course just simply [DROP](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_drop.asp) the tables and start again and it does the same thing.

Comment: thanks for reply. but i can create table in page3 so now i need entire tables delete page one.Give me any idea

Comment: @PavanAlapati: I am sorry, but I didn't quite understand. Please try to write clearer text.

Comment: we have 3 pages like page1,page2 and Page3 we create table1 and table2 in page1.and We create Table3 and table4 in page 3

We need table4 and table3 Delete in page1 .Please guide me

Comment: So why you can't in the first page then do like `tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE table3; DROP TABLE table4;");`?

Comment: we got message undfiend table4 and table3

Comment: Then your `window.openDatabase` probably uses different name for the db on different pages or the tables weren't even created when trying to drop them already.